# How do I insert "-" after the 4th number of 0912345678

Tags: r, regex, gsub

How do I insert "-" between the fourth and fifth numbers of 0912345678 like 0912-345678

I have tried the following code:

```
data_phone_new = readLines("data_phone.txt")
gsub("....()......","-",data_phone_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use groupings. We group the first four characters `(^.{4})` and replace it with the same group `\\1` plus a `-`.

```r
sub("(^.{4})", "\\1-", "0912345678")
#> [1] "0912-345678"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @RitchieSacramento thanks for spotting that, adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub()` as follows:

```r
x <- "0912345678"
output <- sub("(?<=^\\d{4})", "-", x, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "0912-345678"
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex option with `stringr::str_sub`:

```r
library(stringr)
x <- "0912345678"
str_sub(x, 5, 4) <- '-'

#> x
#[1] "0912-345678"
```

Or in base R with `substring`:

```r
paste(substring(x, c(1, 5), c(4, nchar(x))), collapse="-")
#[1] "0912-345678"
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the first 4 digits, and replace with group 1 followed by `-`

```
sub("^(\\d{4})", "\\1-", "0912345678")
```

Output

```
[1] "0912-345678"
```

---

If the whole string must be only 10 digits, you can use 2 capture groups and match 10 digits in total using an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string:

```
sub("^(\\d{4})(\\d{6})$", "\\1-\\2", "0912345678")
```

Output

```
[1] "0912-345678"
```